# How to hide tag in `magit-log`

Tags: magit

Please see the screenshot of my `magit-log-branches`:

[image]

I encounter some projects has lots of tags on each commits, and this situation cause each lines in `magit-log` tooooooooooooooo long and the `magit-log-branches` buffer hardly to read. I Duckduckwent but not found any option to hide the tags in `magit-log` / `magit-log-branches`.

If possible, my wish is to

1. an option to totally hide tag name.
2. or, an option to show only tags count in each commit (for example, a commit has 3 tags on it, shows `(3 tags)` or so),
3. or, an option to make a RegExp pattern to filter out some tags in logs list.

or at least, sort branch name before tag...

Comment: At least in magit log, you can view the log without 'decoration' by pressing `-d` before showing the log. Thus, from the magit status buffer, press `l -d l`.

Comment: @dalanicolai But this also hides branch names...

Comment: Ah too bad. Then I do not know how to achieve it. I guess you should best create a feature request @magit then...